# Is this sentence correct as a title ? Social media's weak signals scanning, for future strategical decisions taking

Tags: titles

I'm trying here to write the title of an article.
the article I'm trying to write is a research topic to apply for a scholarship. (English is my third language)

My article is about detecting the small changes in profiles behaviour on linkedin to predict the changes in a given company.(Eventually where the profile works).

So I thought :

> Social media's weak signals scanning, for future strategical decisions taking

Would be a good title.
What do you guys think?

Comment: It's a perfect title for an article that says nothing.

Comment: I'm having a bad experience on this website. Seriously everyone is trying his best to win the asshole title !

Comment: I was simply saying that if I saw that title I would not bother with the article, because I could safely assume that it was content-free (and, in any event, I would have no idea what the article was about).

Comment: What's wrong with something like "Detecting small changes in profiles on LinkedIn to predict changes in a given company"?

Comment: Because it doesn't sound like an academic article

Comment: It sounds like the serious academic articles I've read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead: `Scanning social media's weak signals for future strategic decisions`

The syntax of your proposed title isn't correct.  You shouldn't divide the title with a comma since it doesn't contain a subjugated clause.  Also, *Strategical* isn't a commonly used word, and the simpler *Strategic* is more appropriate.

Comment: Many thanks Joel, do you think the title reflects the idea of the article ?

Comment: @AymaneShuichi I think the title indicates the content well while maintaining enough mystery to encourage the reader to look further out of curiosity.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote yet ^^